'quarto' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file
I have just installed Quarto 1.6 and restarted my laptop:

Device name   LAPTOP-OVDUFRR7
Processor AMD A9-9425 RADEON R5, 5 COMPUTE CORES 2C+3G      3.10 GHz
Installed RAM 8,00 GB (7,47 GB usable)
System type   64-bit operating system, x64-based processor
Pen and touch No pen or touch input is available for this display

I have included the Path to the Environment Variables

In VSCode I have installed the Quarto Extension..
I can't seem to find anything else online to fix this, please help!

I don't know what "Path to the Environment Variables" means.  You either need to specify the complete path to the executable, or add the folder that contains the executable to your PATH variable.

Everything in that image should be changed. Change, in this sequence, each instance of C:\Users\vagdi\AppData\Local to %LocalAppData%, (your problem one should read as %LocalAppData%\Programs\Quatro\bin), then the instance %UserProfile%\AppData\Local to %LocalAppData%, now C:\Users\vagdi\AppData\Roaming to %AppData%, C:\Program Files to %ProgramFiles%, and finally C:\cygwin64\bin to %SystemDrive%\cygwin64\bin. Please also remove trailing backward slashes from any of those entries too. Also please move %LocalAppdata%\Microsoft\WindowsApps to the top of that list.

Technically the two entries %SystemDrive%\cygwin64\bin, and %ProgramFiles%\Docker\Docker\resources\bin, should be removed from that list and recreated within the System variables Path listing instead of the User variables Path listing shown.
